# Is it possible to hide my app's view in screenshot?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, screenshot

Is it possible to hide or blur the whole screen or part of the screen of my app when the user is taking a screenshot as of iOS 11? If I could get the event *before* the capture I would be able to hide the view, but according to my research, there is an event only *after* the capture.

All StackOverflow and Google search results say preventing screenshot is impossible, but since I had seen an app that did that (though I am not sure it still works on iOS 11), I cannot easily tell the client it is impossible.

When I had an iPad (iOS 10), I could not capture the screen of one Bitcoin wallet app. I tried to save its recovery key screen, but the screenshot image was blurred or something (I cannot remember exactly). I think the app's name was Bread. Unfortunately, right now, I do not have an iOS device, so I cannot test it.

How did the app do it? Did the app modify the captured image after the screenshot event? Is it possible to modify the screenshot silently?

Comment: There's a `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot`notification. But I've never tried if it is send *before* or *after* the screen shot was taken. But it's worth a try.

Comment: According to my research, that is AFTER the screenshot. And unfortunately,  there seems to be no way to get that event in iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add a view in the `applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` method in you appDelegate. For example you can add a blur view in this delegate method so you screenshot will be blurred. This delegate method is called the moment the home button is tapped once or twice.

Comment: this will not work if user try to take screenshot using Home+Power button.but i see many application also prevent ScreenShot from Home+Power button like confide,blackbox game.